# Obtain the source of a MediaWiki page programmatically

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to obtain the source of a MediaWiki page programmatically? I'd like to write a function that does the following (in Java-like pseudocode):

```
public static String getWikiText(articleURL){
//return the source of the page as wiki markup
}
```

Comment: Perhaps additional information can be found here (but I haven't found this information yet): http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a HTTP request with [action=raw](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#Raw). (You could use the API as well, but that is more complicated.)